# How can I modify a textview from a non-activity class? Android

Tags: android, notifications, textview, remoteview

I want to modify a TextView from an alarmmanager class's onReceive method this class does not extend activity. The alarm sends an intent that creates a notification and I want to make it so clicking the notification will open a textview with a particular string that I get in this onReceive method.

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.notify_layout);

contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notetext,my_message);
notif.contentView = contentView;
```

I tried to do this using the RemoteView above with the notification intent but it doesn't seem to work.

I know I can't access this using findViewById, but what approach should I take here?

This is from the code that handles the intent

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.notify_layout);

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) 
    getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); nm.cancel(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("com.myapp.NotificationDisp"));
```

Then I have this whole notification thing here. I know that its deprecated and I should be using builder but I need this to be compatible back to gingerbread which it seems builder is not.

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.MyApp.NotificationDisp");
            i.putExtra("com.MyApp.NotificationDisp", 1);
            nm = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    "Myapp", System.currentTimeMillis());
                  //

                 RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.notify_layout);
                  contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notetext,
                    my_message);
                  notif.contentView = contentView;
                  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                            i, 0);
                  notif.contentIntent = contentIntent;
                  //
                  notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Myapp", my_message, contentIntent);
                  notif.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500}; 
                  nm.notify(1, notif);
```

So this brings up a notification with the correct text in my status bar but when I click on it it only shows a blank textview. The xml notify_layout should be setup fine.

Comment: you could make your BroadCast receiver as an inner class of the Activity that does have the TextView in it, then it would have access to the TextView reference so it could call `setText()` on it.

Comment: I have an activity that handles this intent and opens up the view I want, but it doesn't change the text to what I need it to. The notification contentText field has the String in it though. Can I access that directly using getIntent()?

Comment: I don't think so, not unless you added the string as an Extra to your intent. Can you post some more of your alarm manager and receiver code? I can't really tell what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I edited it to include some more code, I want to change the text on the textview each time onReceive runs

Comment: For anyone maybe wondering I fixed the problem by moving the message logic to the activity for handling the notification intent.